# Magento - Multi Select Category Attribute not saving

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

I'm using Magento Community 1.9.0.0.

I have programmatically created a custom category attribute which is a multi select. The attribute can be seen in my admin category section. When i select any values - whether it's one or more and press save i get a successful saved message but the values never save.

I then also tried an extension which creates category attributes. This had the same issue. When i contacted support they said

***Category entity does not support multi selection so this type of attribute will not work with category.***

Is this true? Can multi select not work on category attributes on CE-1.9?

Here is the code i was using to create it programmatically:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Room Type',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information",
    'option' => array ( 
        'value' => array(
            'kitchen' => array('Kitchen'), 
            'bedroom' => array('Bedroom'), 
            'bathroom' => array('Bathroom'), 
            'loft' => array('Loft'), 
            'basement' => array('Basement'), 
            'lounge' => array('Lounge')
        ) 
    )

);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'room_type', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Multiselect should definitely work with category attributes.
Follow this tutorial. It's for textarea but you can create one for dropdown in similar way. 
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: Do you know any reason why it might not be saving then?

Comment: Did you create a source model? Post your code here.

Comment: Code now added above. I haven't got a source model. What would i put there?

Answer (score 1):

@Rian is right, multi-select values are sent as an array, which can't be processed. However, we don't have to use observer. Instead, we should add a backend model for the attribute.
Add the following line to your attribute data array when creating it.

```
'backend' => 'your_module/category_attribute_backend_related',
```

In your backend model (`Your_Module_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Related`), you should have the following functions to help the selected options be saved or loaded correctly.

```
public function beforeSave($object) {
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    if ($attributeCode == 'room_type') {
        $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            $data = array();
        }
        $object->setData($attributeCode, join(',', $data));
    }
    if (is_null($object->getData($attributeCode))) {
        $object->setData($attributeCode, false);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function afterLoad($object) {
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    if ($attributeCode == 'room_type') {
        $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
        if ($data) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, explode(',', $data));
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this question is a bit old, but I figure better late than never.

Categories can work splendidly with multi selects, you just have to help them along a bit. Multiselects are sent to the category entity as an array, which it can't process, meaning you end up with an empty multiselect. What you want to do is merge the ids into a single string. Either using javascript, or as I did, using an observer.

My multiselect attribute is called `category_limit`.

This goes in the `config.xml`

```ml
<events>
    <catalog_category_prepare_save>
        <observers>
            <rianorie_categorylimit_save>
                <class>rianorie_categorylimit/observer</class>
                <method>adjustCategory</method>
            </rianorie_categorylimit_save>
        </observers>
    </catalog_category_prepare_save>
</events>
```

and this is the actual observer doing the work:

```php
class RianOrie_CategoryLimit_Model_Observer
{
    public function adjustCategory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $category = $event->getCategory();
        $category->setCategoryLimit(
              implode(',', $category->getCategoryLimit())
        );
    }
}
```